# Class diagram multiplicity and implementation

Tags: class, uml, class-diagram

After reading a lot, I was quite confident when it came to class diagrams. Yet I do not understand the following:

```
ChessManSet-<>----------16-ChessMan
```

Why is there not 0..16? Player can loose his chessman. This was displayed in a model done by a respected designer in my company and when I asked about that, he said only "they still belong to him".
So I'm a bit confused, I would expect that to be implemented as a list which obviously could decrease in its size from 16 to 0.

Comment: Zero is not a valid number of chess pieces (the game ends before the King is captured)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only sure thing is that according to your model or design in the implementation you will always have 16 chessman instances.
Of course you can choose to implement a list which could decrease from 16 to 0 but, as you said, you have to change the cardinality from 16..16 to 0..16.

Comment: Exactly but why would you keep 16 instances all the time? Even when removed..Does not make sense to me.

Comment: I agree that I did not see why you need to always keep all of them but maybe I miss something... 
The main thing is that you correctly read your diagram if it does not match with your implementation you have to change one of them (the design or implementation).